# How to set auth method in pear mail

Tags: php, pear

I just need help setting the auth type in pear mail. This is the array I have currently.. auth is set to true, but I need it to be true and set to LOGIN method. Can anyone help me out with the syntax for this?

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://server.net',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'timeout' => 20,
        'username' => 'theusername',
        'password' => 'thepassword'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php#9454 you should set the `auth` field to `"LOGIN"` and not just `true`.

Comment: Thanks! Thought that's what it should be, but doing it that way didn't fix the authentication problems I had, so was doubting myself.